# Getting nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException when converting json in java object in angulajs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, data-binding

Whenever I'm sending JSON from client to server and it tries to convert this JSON into java object. It is giving following exception

Failed to read HTTP message:

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: N/A\n at [Source:
>   java.io.PushbackInputStream@18f89001; line: 1, column: 1102] (through
>   reference chain:
>   Request["fields"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->Field["value"]); nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException

My java code:

```
public class Field implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String value;

    public Field(){
    }

    public Field(String name, String value ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String newValue) throws Exception {
        someValidation();//Some validation on value
        value = newValue;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Request implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private List<Field> fields;

    public Request() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return viewName;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Field>  getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
    public void setField(List<Field>  fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }
}
```

My JSON is :

```
{
"name" : "name0",
"fields" : [{"name":"abc0", "value":"0"}, {"name":"def0", "value":"0"}]
}
```

Comment: can you please provide controller class and mapping?

Comment: I'm doing some validation when setting value which is cause issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine, I think the problem might be with your request header, which can confuse the server.
I suggest you try to post a simpler JSON to your server, maybe just a string and find out step by step where is your failure point, check your request and maybe simulate one with POSTMAN or something familiar to make sure the client isn't the problem here.